# how to make the footer down below and vertical?

Tags: css, footer

how to make the footer down below and vertical?
I want it for the mobile version to make the footer down below.
I tried many solutions but it didn't work very well.
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMoVi.png)
as you see it become like this, I don't know if it's from the footer or the content itself?

```
/* mobile styles */
    .footer {
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .footer .footer-content {
        height: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .footer .footer-content .footer-section {
        height: auto;
    }
/* desktop styles */
    .footer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer .footer-bottom {    
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.footer .footer-content {
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
}
.footer .footer-content .footer-section {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

If you are using bootstrap simply use col classes